# Do I need to verify captcha every time?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed when I tried to answer questions, two times in a row it asked me to verify the captcha. Will it happen every time I answer a question? If yes, then it's a very bad UX.

[image]

Comment: Without more specific details about how you're posting answers, I've closed this question as a duplicate of the rate limiting guide, which has a section about when users are presented with Captchas while answering. If you don't feel that your answers fit any of these patterns, edit your question to explain how you are answering in more detail so we can better determine whether something is amiss.

Comment: OKay I'll read the guide first